# Show that every root of a polynomial is real (using Galois theory)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

**The question**

Let $f$ be a rational polynomial (so $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$) of degree $4$. Let $E$ be the splitting field of $f$ such that $[E:\mathbb{Q}] = 12$ and assume that $f$ has one real root $z$. Show that all roots of $f$ are real.

**The problem**

So I tried looking at this in multiple ways. The degree of the polynomial is $4$, so I know that $-z$ is also a root (which seems right to me). Now I'm trying to figure out what the other roots are by using Galois Theory. The things I already know now are:

- The Galois group of this extension has degree $12$, because this is a Galois extension
- Now the issue I'm having is the fact that the degree is $12$. This seems somewhat 'unreal' to me: look at the field $\mathbb{Q}(z)$. This field lies between $E$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ because it is an extension of degree $4$. Now the two other roots (call them $x$ and $-x$) should be roots of a third degree polynomial to make the degree $12$, but there are only two roots left and their minimal polynomial is $f$ divided by the two factors with $z$ and $-z$. So in my eyes the degree is $8$ here...

What am I seeing wrong? And how could I solve this question then?

Comment: For $-z$ to also be a root you would need $f$ to be *biquadratic* (even degree terms only).

Comment: I understand. I assumed there were none which is my mistake.

Comment: Any tips on how the solve the problem, then?

Comment: 1. show f is irreducible. 2. [Q(z) : Q] =4, [E: Q(z)] =3, let w be a root not in Q(z), the mininal polynomial g of w over Q(z)  must be of degree 3, real polynomial of odd degree has a real root, say y, then Q(z,y) already equal E, and Q(z,y) is real.

Comment: @user119882 this approach is very smart and simple. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: sorry for the smartphone-typing, so make that comment.

Comment: @user119882 I think your idea is great, and sorta gets away with less technology than mine. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Extended hints:

Remember that we can think of the Galois group $G$ as a group of permutations of the roots, in this case $G\le S_4$.

1. Show that $A_4$ is the only subgroup of order $12$.
2. Complex conjugation is of order two. We know that its counterpart in $G$ has at least one fixed point, namely $z$. Actually, it must have an even number of fixed points, why?
3. Show that the only permutation of $A_4$ that has an even **positive** number of fixed points is the identity. Why does this settle your question?

Comment: I think I understand everything now, apart from the second tip. Is this because the order of complex conjugation is 2?

Comment: Yes, @xzeo. The non-real roots come in complex conjugate **pairs**...

Comment: @xzeo Because complex conjugation is of order 2, you will break a set of size 4 into orbits of size 1 and 2.